# Using metadata api to deploy to production org

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

I used the `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --retrievetargetdir force-app  -k manifest/package.xml` command to pull down the source metadata from a production org. The retrieval process successfully ran and the zipfile was stored in the project force-app directory called unpackaged.zip.

I now want to use the mdapi:deploy option and deploy the metadata to a completely different production org. Do I need to rerun authorize org and connect to the different production org that I'm targeting? How do I make sure that I've correctly authorized and pointed to the production target org? Also, I only want to run a check first so I can just add the --checkonly parameter? Do I need to extract the metadata in the unpackaged.zip file into the `force-app/main/default/` directory? Or, can I just point to the unpackaged.zip file to run the deploy?

I haven't gone thru this process using the sfdx commands and am unsure of the exact steps I need to take. All I'm trying to do at the moment is just run a check and verify if the deployment will be successful or get a list of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to rerun authorize org and connect to the different production org that I'm targeting?

Unless you're other org is already authorized, then yes, you need to do so.

> How do I make sure that I've correctly authorized and pointed to the production target org?

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

Will show you the currently connected orgs. If set to default, it will have `(U)` next to it. If not, you can set the default with:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=name-or-alias
```

Or you can deploy with the `-u` option.

> Also, I only want to run a check first so I can just add the --checkonly parameter?

Yes, you can do that. Once the check passes, you can then use Quick Deploy if you want to avoid having to run tests again (if applicable).

> Do I need to extract the metadata in the unpackaged.zip file into the force-app/main/default/ directory? Or, can I just point to the unpackaged.zip file to run the deploy?

Both options are supported. Use whichever you prefer. `-d` points to a directory in MDAPI format, `-f` refers to a ZIP file. You may also need `-s` either way, if the package is a "single package" format (e.g. it has package.xml in the root folder, rather than multiple folders with individual package.xml files).